# Texture Usage in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am creating a drawing application using Metal. For brush I am using texture to draw on touched points. I am using the same texture in the touched points. when touch point size increase to 3000 to 4000 draw cycle the FPS drops from 120 to 4. Any optimized way to do the same texture.

Comment: How you draw? with vertex shader or compute shader?

Comment: with Vertex Shader